# How to group data in MySQL for every 3 hours from today?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to retrieve data for one of my charts and I'd like to come up with a simple solution for it, instead of doing 8 subqueries.

This is how the `users` table looks like:

```
user_id
1
2
3
4
5
```

This is how the `pts` table looks like:

```
id  user_id  status  points                 time
1         1       0      100  2014-08-23 03:34:54
2         4       0      100  2014-08-23 04:04:44
3         1       1      300  2014-08-23 08:34:21
4         1       0      300  2014-08-23 15:25:11
5         1       0      200  2014-08-23 22:23:12
```

The query looks something like this (with a few comments, where I didn't know what to put):

```
    "SELECT  *,
        (
            SELECT  SUM(points)
            FROM    pts
            WHERE   status = 0 
            AND     user_id = 1
            AND     time >= "THIS DAY'S 00:00" AND <= "THIS DAY'S 03:00" 
        ),
        (
            SELECT  SUM(points)
            FROM    pts
            WHERE   status = 0 
            AND     user_id = 1
            AND     time >= "THIS DAY'S 03:00" AND <= "THIS DAY'S 06:00"
        ),
        (
            SELECT  SUM(points)
            FROM    pts
            WHERE   status = 0
            AND     user_id = 1 
            AND     time >= "THIS DAY'S 06:00" AND <= "THIS DAY'S 09:00"
        ),
        (
            SELECT  SUM(points)
            FROM    pts
            WHERE   status = 0 
            AND     user_id = 1
            AND     time >= "THIS DAY'S 12:00" AND <= "THIS DAY'S 15:00"
        ),
"ETC......"
FROM    pts
WHERE   user_id = 1
AND     status  = 1
"
```

So basically the query needs to collect data from the Database on the current day for each 3 hours (so it would be 8 sub queries if I'd go with the above option). Also the query should return 0 / null if the current time is not reached yet for the interval. If the current time is in one ofthe intervals it should return the data from the start of the interval till the end of the interval.

The result I would like to achieve:

```
id  user_id  points                                       time
1         1       0  2014-08-23 00:00:00 - 2014-08-23 03:00:00
2         1     200  2014-08-23 03:00:00 - 2014-08-23 06:00:00
3         1     300  2014-08-23 06:00:00 - 2014-08-23 09:00:00
4         1       0  2014-08-23 09:00:00 - 2014-08-23 12:00:00
5         1       0  2014-08-23 12:00:00 - 2014-08-23 15:00:00
6         1     300  2014-08-23 15:00:00 - 2014-08-23 18:00:00
7         1       0  2014-08-23 18:00:00 - 2014-08-23 21:00:00
8         1     200  2014-08-23 21:00:00 - 2014-08-23 00:00:00
```

IS this possible with MySQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use aggregation and arithmetic on the hour:

```
select floor(hour(time) / 3) as hourgroup, sum(points)
from pts
where status = 0 and user_id = 1 and
      date(time) = "THIS DAY"
group by floor(hour(time) / 3);
```

For your particular output:

```
select (hour(time) div 3) as id, user_id, sum(points),
       date('2014-08-23') + interval 3 * (hour(time) div 3) hour as starttime,
       date('2014-08-23') + interval 3 * ((hour(time) div 3) + 1) hour as endtime
from pts
where status = 0 and user_id = 1 and
      date(time) = date('2014-08-23')
group by floor(hour(time) / 3);
```

There is an issue with the values where the counts are zero.  I'm not sure how important these are.  Your query pivots the data, yet your desired results are not pivoted.

EDIT:

If you really need the times for all groups, you can do:

```
select n.n as id, user_id, sum(points),
       date('2014-08-23') + interval 3 * n.n hour as starttime,
       date('2014-08-23') + interval 3 * (n.n + 1) hour as endtime
from (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
      select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
     ) n left join
     pts
     on n.n = hour(time) div 3
where status = 0 and user_id = 1 and
      date(time) = date('2014-08-23')
group by n.n;
```

Comment: (+1)An alternative would be the DIV operator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works pretty well, except you've mentioned. The query does not displays when there is no result. It would be great though. Is there any way around that problem?

Comment: Your edited answer is basically giving back the exact same results, than the simpler one. Am I missing something here?