# Subtotal in a query- MySQL

Tags: mysql, loops

I have a MySQL table data with timeline data (YYYY-MM-DD hh:MM)

| time_log | M0 | M1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 06:00:00 | 10 | 30 |
| 2022-01-01 07:00:00 | 10 | 30 |
| 2022-01-01 08:00:00 | 10 | 30 |
| 2022-01-01 09:00:00 | 10 | 30 |
| 2022-01-01 10:00:00 | 10 | 30 |
| 2022-01-01 11:00:00 | 10 | 30 |
| 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | 10 | 30 |
| 2022-01-01 13:00:00 | 10 | 30 |
| 2022-01-01 14:00:00 | 10 | 30 |
| 2022-01-01 15:00:00 | 10 | 30 |

i am able to write a query to get subtotal of data by hardcoding the query like below

```
SELECT sum(M0), sum(M1) from hourdata WHERE time_log >= '2022-01-01 06:00:00' AND time_log < '2022-01-01 08:00:00';
SELECT sum(M0), sum(M1) from hourdata WHERE time_log >= '2022-01-01 08:00:00' AND time_log < '2022-01-01 10:00:00';
```

But I need answer in a single query

how is the query constructed for this ?

Comment: You want these two specific queries together? Or a total for every two hours?

Comment: You combine query results using `union`

Comment: use group by with CASE statement

Comment: If you want every two hours - look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473331/how-to-group-data-in-mysql-for-every-3-hours-from-today

Comment: You can update the where clause of the query. For example: ```SELECT sum(M0), sum(M1) from hourdata WHERE time_log >= '2022-01-01 06:00:00' AND time_log < '2022-01-01 10:00:00';```